# .NET 4 Framework Client Profile Install -- Repeats Install Failure

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, .net-framework

> Final Result: Installation failed with
>   error code: WM_ACTIVATEAPP: Focus
>   stealer's windows WAS visible, NOT
>   taking back focus
>   Sending Manifest Report

My .NET 4 Framework installation keeps failing with the above "final result" message. Is this a known issue? And if so, what is the fix?

Comment: can you post the full log?

Comment: No sorry. But I did discover resetting the Windows Update components allows a successful install of .NET 4 Framework (when receiving this error code).

Comment: Ok, so no problems then? If so post the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset Windows Update components. In this particular case I used a utility provided by Microsoft called Fix It with the aggressive option checked.

**Please note it is not recommended to use the aggressive option**